# Ajax Values not updating in php - Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a ajax call which send values to php like so

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: '/app/itemmanagement',
    data: {
        activity_type: window.location.hash
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("succes");
        // alert("success!");
    }
});
```

I get the values from the ajax using `INPUT` and pass to a partial like so

```
<?php
    $activity_type = Input::get('activity_type');
    xdebug_break();
    $activity_type = isset($activity_type) ? substr($activity_type,1) : 'new';
?>

@include('partials.layouts._core_activity_header',['layout_type' => $activity_type])
```

The partial is not getting updated when the ajax sends the data.

```
<div id="core-activity-name" class="core-display-align core-p-2">
    <?php
        $type = '';
        if($layout_type == 'reports'){
            $type = 'All';
            $type_opp = 'New';
        }else if($layout_type == 'new'){
            $type = 'New';
            $type_opp = 'View';
        }
        ?>
    <a class="core-remove-a-styling"  href="#">{{ $type }} Item Management</a>
</div>
```

The variable `$type` always outputs **New** it is not updating to **All**,can someone tell me why it is not updating and what is wrong in my code/logic?

Comment: how do you call the ajax? and what is the value of `$activity_type`?

Comment: ajax is called on page load and $activity_type is the hash from the link.

Comment: `console.log(window.location.hash)` on javascript side, `echo $activity_type;` on php side, see what their value

Comment: You're not doing anything with the `success` callback. That's where you would be updating your markup.